# EFCore cannot get new value in docker, if use rsync replace sqlite file

Tags: .net, docker, sqlite, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Program environment

```
.NET6
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite:  6.0.9
Docker Desktop:  20.10.16
OS: Win10
```

I create an asp.net core project, which has an API query SQLite

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class HomeController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly HeroDbContext _dbContext;

    public HomeController(HeroDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    [HttpGet("{id:int}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var hero = await _dbContext.Heroes.FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id, cancellationToken);
        var response = new { Data = hero, Successed = hero != null };
        return Ok(response);
    }
}
```

I deploy the project using the docker base on wsl2:
 `docker run -d --name ddocker -p 9100:80  -v /mnt/c/Users/chiwenjun/Desktop/pdemo/docs/:/home/db/ ddocker`

If I change the SQLite file in `/mnt/c/Users/chiwenjun/Desktop/pdemo/docs` directory directly, the API can return the new value. But, if use rsync command sync a new SQLite file into the  `/mnt/c/Users/chiwenjun/Desktop/pdemo/docs` directory replace the old file, the value returned by the API was not changed.

I use python fastapi to write an API query the same SQLite file, it's can return the new value.

```py
class HeroDbContext:
    def __init__(self, conn_str):
        self.__conn_str = conn_str
        self.__conn = sqlite3.connect(conn_str)

    async def __aenter__(self):
        if self.__conn is None:
            self.__conn = sqlite3.connect(self.__conn_str)
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, ex_type, ex_value, ex_traceback) -> bool:
        if self.__conn is not None:
            self.__conn.close()
        return True

    def get_by_id(self, id: int) -> Union[Hero, None]:
        try:
            cur = self.__conn.cursor()
            r = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Heros WHERE Id=:id", [id])
            return self.__handle_db_result(r)
        finally:
            cur.close()

    def __handle_db_result(self, result: Cursor) -> Optional[Hero]:
        if result is None:
            return None
        data = result.fetchone()
        return None if data is None else Hero(data[0], data[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `Pooling=False` can resolve this problem.
Reference: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/29302